# I am having errors when I try to install mingw c++ compiler for windows 10

Tags: mingw

Hi I am experiencing error when I try to install minGW. This is the error message. Why is this happening?
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** http://osdn.net/dl/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.3-mingw32-pre-20170905-1-bin.tar.xz:cannot open URL; status lic.tar.xz:cannot open URL; status = 12007
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://osdn.net/dl/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.3-mingw32-pre-20170905-1-

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're installing from the official http://mingw.org/ site.

MinGW is old, I recommend you use MinGW-w64 instead. A standalone build (which doesn't need installing, just extract to a folder) is available from http://winlibs.com/